# Why are the following suggested edits being rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, edits, rejected-edits

**[Case 1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5391084)**

- A suggested edit gets approved by 2 users, and is then followed by three rejections. The reasons given for the rejections have exactly the same text. So, no point is made or clarified (see question bellow).
- This answer edit was previously commented as an improvement by the author of the answer.

  *Result*: The author has to edit himself and saved a otherwise lost answer quality improvement.

  Question:

  - Why is it "*incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post*"? For sure not a reply, neither a comment as no text is added. Is it incorrect?! Original author does not think so.

**[Case 2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5414464)**

- In less than 1 minute a Java answer code edition was rejected by 3 users. Again, not giving the reasoning for rejections, one finds that 2 of the 3 users do not even have a Java related tag in their profile, and the other has a lonely Java tag at the end of their tag list.
- In more than 1 hour, no one, including the edit rejectors, answers a short and direct comment asking for a code part inclusion in the answer (naturally not mentioning directly the edit).

  *Result*: No learning outcome or answer quality improvement... no edit suggestion or edit acceptance/rejection improvement.

  Questions:

  1. Why does "*This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost*"? The extra object and calendar set call is redundant. The remainder meaning is equivalent. Follows [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) as *clarifies the meaning of a post without changing it*.
  2. Why "*This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post*"?

Comment: *The reasons pointed for rejections are exactly the same text.* That's because the review system offers several reasons for rejecting a suggested edit, and those 3 reviewers agreed on why it should be rejected.

Comment: Suggested edit reviewers *cannot see the comments on the post*, so any suggested editor should really provide that context. State *in the edit summary* that an edit was requested by the post author, for example.

Comment: **Because** reviewers are not expected to have domain knowledge, don't suggest edits that require such. Gain enough trust (e.g. reputation) to make edits outright instead.

Comment: Wouldn't a more detailed or directed reason be more productive? That way the editor would be more likely to learn about his/her error(s). Another possible outcome would be the edit reviewer give it a bit more deserved time and also learn something.

Comment: We have the options to write a custom rejection reason if necessary, but generally one of the standard rejection reasons fits. If the 3 reasons were the same, all the more likely that the edit clearly failed for the reason given.

Comment: That doesn't scale; on a site like Stack Overflow there are *thousands* of suggested edits to be reviewed each day. Count for today (UTC, so 11 hours so far): 2,759 reviews.

Comment: @JoséAndias: a custom field option is available, but the standard reasons are usually more than sufficient.

Comment: _Suggested edit reviewers cannot see the comments on the post_. Is this the best way? And it seems there is no notice about that in the edit dialog.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters about _Because reviewers are not expected ..._ Sorry, did not figured that suggest editions were not supposed to be done by users with that post domain knowledge.

Comment: It's best to not make assumptions about how much context is visible to reviewers. The [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) does provide guidelines on editing, and the rejection reasons are aligned with those; editing beyond those guidelines requires that you put in the extra mile to make it easier on the reviewers.

Comment: @OGHaza: Do the reviewers that follow see the previous reasons? If so, I think that unfortunately that also makes the following reason more likely the same as previous.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters about _That doesn't scale ..._:  If it is a problem there are thousands of suggested edits to be reviewed, maybe there should be another criterion for a edit beeing permited or beeing reviewed... I don't think loosing post quality improvement should be lost to that.

Comment: @JoséAndias: This only applies to users < 2k; e.g. users we don't quite trust yet to know what is appropriate to edit and how the site works.

Comment: @JoséAndias: There is plenty of room for quality improvements with this system, but with sensible constraints.

Comment: Note that in both of your rejected edits (I only checked to past 2) you were editing someone else's code. I too would have rejected such edits.

Comment: Although I still stand for most of my previous opinions, I am a lot more enlightened already after this discussion. Thank you fellow commenters! It is a shame others don't feel it like me and think the question does not show research effort, is not useful neither clear. I guess it is pressingly the opposite. Sorry all for that!

Comment: @OGHaza: I was avoiding getting the question particularized to frame it in a more broad discussion. But concerning that, what is the difference from code and other text edition? Ain't them both expressions of an answer? Some people are more code expressing and other less... How to reason about code being more sensible than plain English is that it? (**probably this discussion fits another frame no?**)

Comment: @OGHaza: Did you just voted it down? lol Just some humor!

Comment: I downvoted this question before my initial comment, it's nothing personal, but the general tone of your post is "good edits are being rejected, should we do something about it?", to which my response would be "I reject the premise that there is a problem with any more than a negligible number of good edits being rejected". Hence the down vote. As for code edits, there's some [guidelines here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) and if you search for "code edits" you'll find a fair amount of discussion.

Comment: OGHaza: Thank you. For the first example I think it was clearly a _To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place_. Do you thing I should open another question particularizing the rejection of this edit?

Comment: OGHaza: I can't see where the second example fits in the guidelines you provide... (what I did was removed redundant code improving code readability and understanding). Could you help please? Should I open another question?

Comment: Shifted question frame, hopefully to a more community useful one. (Related to @OGHaza comment on downvoted. I upvoted that comment and it's also nothing personal ;) )

Comment: @JoséAndias Changing code for suggested edits is highly discouraged. Those who review suggested edits are not required to have *any* knowledge of the coding language that the question is about. Even if they do, changing code with a suggested edit is not allowed because it may not be what the author had intended.

Comment: @Anonymous: So I can assume an edition is not supposed to improve in the knowledge programming/developing area of the question/answer as that skills are not intended for a review?

Comment: @JoséAndias You can comment on the post so that the author knows. Otherwise, you should wait until you have 2000 reputation.

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, I have done that in case 1. In case 2 I have done as a last resort. Ok, for me it seems that waiting for 2k reputation is the only "reasonable" way about this. I have to unbosom that this (consecutive) cases left me unmotivated to further Stackoverflow participation.

Answer (score 8):

Given suggestions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5414464) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5391084), I think you'd be safer sticking with more prudent [editing philosophy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194863/165773):

> **to readers (including original author of the edited content), it shouldn't look like you added something of "your own"... it shouldn't look like you introduced something that wasn't there in the mind of original author...**

Comment: Voted up and used links in edit of question. I can't see neither as something "of my own". Clearly in case 1 the original idea is kept, no new idea introduced and the wrong API usage is corrected. In case 2 once again, no new idea is introduced, neither the original idea is changed. Either that or I misunderstood the original idea, witch for now and naturally, I don't believe so.